# Make the sound from a video on a website exit through the earpiece

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio

Is this possible with HTML/CSS or jQuery ?
I want to make a small audioguide, and it will be listen outdoor, near a river and i want the user to be able to listen to it with the earpiece.

Comment: What do you mean by "the earpiece"? Do you simply want the audio to play?

Comment: Why couldn't it be possible???

Comment: I thought I had your answer and then I realize you didn't need a sound upon website exit...you want to exit through earphones? I'm with the guys above me here. Why wouldn't this be possible normally?

Comment: In fact i want the sound to output where you put your ear to listen to your mom for exemple, heh.